# Oracle (10g) equivalent of DATEADD(weekday, -3, GETDATE())

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I'm looking for the Oracle (10g) equivalent of:

```
DATEADD(weekday, -3, GETDATE())
```

from T-SQL (SQL Server) .  This [subtracts 3 weekdays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) from the current date.  I'm not concerned about holidays or anything like that (and I can truncate the time part off myself).  Just excluding weekends is fine.

Comment: The direct equivalent of `DATEADD(weekday, -3, GETDATE())` then is `select trunc(sysdate) - 3 from dual`. I realise this has already been answered in more detail, but its this simple solution that I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to create a UDF.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION business_date (start_date DATE, 
days2add NUMBER) RETURN DATE IS
 Counter NATURAL := 0;
 CurDate DATE := start_date;
 DayNum POSITIVE;
 SkipCntr NATURAL := 0;
 Direction INTEGER := 1;  -- days after start_date
 BusinessDays NUMBER := Days2Add;
BEGIN
  IF Days2Add < 0 THEN
    Direction := - 1; -- days before start_date
    BusinessDays := (-1) * BusinessDays;
  END IF;

  WHILE Counter < BusinessDays LOOP
    CurDate := CurDate + Direction;
    DayNum := TO_CHAR( CurDate, 'D');

    IF DayNum BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
      Counter := Counter + 1;
    ELSE
      SkipCntr := SkipCntr + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN start_date + (Direction * (Counter + SkipCntr));
END business_date;
```

Courtesy of Larry Benton, from [here](http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html).

Answer (score 5):

It can be done without a PL/SQL function. Just subtract a different number of days depending on the day of the week:

```
select trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'D')
                        when '4' then 3 -- thursday minus 3 days
                        when '5' then 3 -- friday minus 3 days
                        when '6' then 4 -- saturday minus 4 days
                        else 5          -- all other days minus 5 days
                        end
from dual;
```

When you have to do this for e.g. 12 days back, it would look like:

```
select trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'D')
                        when '1' then 18 -- mondays minus 18 days (incl. 3 weekends)
                        when '2' then 18 -- tuesdays minus 18 days (incl. 3 weekends)
                        when '6' then 17 -- saturdays minus 17 days (incl. 2 weekends and a saturday)
                        else 16          -- all others minus 16 days (incl. 2 weekends)
                        end
from dual;
```

Please note that day of week depends on the NLS_TERRITORY of your database (in America day 1 is Sunday, in most others day 1 is Monday).

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for a small number of days (like the 3 in my example) where multiple weekends cannot be a factor.

Comment: Can you give an example? I think my solution can easily be adjusted to any number of days.

Comment: when the number is larger than 5 you have to account for multiple weekends depending on how many you hit.

Comment: @Cade Roux, the logic does not change. I added an example to my answer.