# How to get 6 months from a parametrized date

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a where clause where I am trying to get a date within a certain range with parameters like so,

```
 (AL.INSERTED_DATE BETWEEN (:begindate) AND (:enddate))
```

The problem is that I need to get six months before the begin date but I get an error, ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier,  when I try,

```
 (AL.INSERTED_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(Month,-6,(:begindate)) AND (:enddate))
```

Can anybody point me out to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: That's an Oracle error message with Oracle notation for variables.  Your problem is that you're using a MS-SQL-Server function in Oracle...

Comment: I am getting this error message in ssrs report designer. I looked it up and DATEADD is a tsql function.

Comment: Your error message is not from SQL Server.  Your error message is from Oracle.  I'm sorry, that's just fact.  Somewhere along the line, your SSRS Report is running SQL on Oracle and ***NOT*** SQL Server.  So, yes, you're right that `DATEADD()` is T-SQL and so it works in SQL Server. ***But your SQL is not running on SQL Server.***

Comment: Im running against a oracle database but the code still needs to be in T-SQL correct? When you try to use oracle sql code it does not always work. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong.  Your SQL needs to be Oracle.  Note, for example, that you use `:begindate` where T-SQL would use `@begindate`.

Comment: Thanks man this really clears everything up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using SQL Server, you're using Oracle - that's why it's giving you an error in Oracle format.

http://psoug.org/definition/ADD_MONTHS.htm

ADD_MONTHS would probably be the best equivalent to what you're trying to do here -

```
  (AL.INSERTED_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS((:begindate),-6) AND (:enddate))
```

Comment: I always assumed that oracle code would not work in reporting services so i had to manually translate to t-sql. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

[Oracle (10g) equivalent of DATEADD(weekday, -3, GETDATE())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670194/oracle-10g-equivalent-of-dateaddweekday-3-getdate)