# Next Business day from a date including US Holidays in Oracle SQL - no pl/sql code

Tags: sql, oracle, date

After reading and trying many sql codes, am still facing the issue.

i need to calculate the 5th Businessday from a date.

i need to remove 'saturday' 'sunday' and US Holidays

i have a table which consists of US Holidays but coudn't able to join them properly in my sql

```
    BDATE       WEEKDAY_INDI
   ----------  --------------
1   6/1/2014    WEEKEND
2   6/2/2014    WEEKDAY
3   6/3/2014    WEEKDAY
4   6/4/2014    WEEKDAY
5   6/5/2014    WEEKDAY
6   6/6/2014    WEEKDAY
7   6/7/2014    WEEKEND
8   6/8/2014    WEEKEND
```

like wise i can get the weekdays and holidays in a table / separate tables

I have a query

```
select * from ODM.team
```

which gives

```
   NAME       DOB         DOB_MONTH   DOJ         UPDATED_DATE
  ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
1  Afnand     9/14/2000   September   2/20/2012   6/12/2014
2  Angil      10/9/2000   October      5/5/2014   6/10/2014
3  Asthwini   5/17/2000   May          4/6/2011   6/02/2014
```

I want to calculare the next Business day to `UPDATED_DATE`

For that i have treid to join the holidays table with the Team table, but it didn't worked

Can you please suggest me how to get the next 5 th business day (excluding weekends, holidays).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670194/oracle-10g-equivalent-of-dateaddweekday-3-getdate

Comment: thnx lalit, but all i know is to join the Team table with the holidays table to get the next business days . . . but the link gives me the solution for saller queries only, this i need to implement for larger one

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
with holidays as (
  select bdate, 
         case when rnd = 1 then 'WEEKEND' else 'WEEKDAY' end weekday_indi 
  from (select trunc(sysdate) - lvl bdate, round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) rnd from (select level lvl 
         from dual connect by level <= 100)
       )
),
team as (
  select 1 name, trunc(sysdate) - 50 updated_date from dual  
) 
*/
select /* other t columns*/ name, updated_date, next5 from
(
  select /* other t columns*/t.name, t.updated_date, 
         lead(decode(h.weekday_indi, 'WEEKEND', null, h.bdate) ignore nulls, 5) 
         over (partition by name order by h.bdate) next5,
         row_number() over (partition by t.name order by h.bdate) rw
  from team t left join holidays h on t.updated_date <= h.bdate
) where rw = 1;
```

You can use Oracle analytic LEAD function WITH IGNORE NULLS option.

`lead(decode(h.weekday_indi, 'WEEKEND', null, h.bdate) ignore nulls, 5)` - if it's WEEKEND make bdate null and find the 5th bdate which is greater then current row (ignoring nulls)

1. Make left nonequi-join to find dates for each row in the team table which are equal or greater than updated_date
2. For each row in the resulting query find next 5th bdate ignoring weekends inside the group defined in PARTITION BY
3. Get only the first row in each group (= all rows from the team table)

May not work properly if there is no bdate = updated_date in the HOLIDAYS table

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with the assumption you have a version of Oracle with Window Aggregate methods, specifically `LEAD()`.

time_master

```
  BDATE   WEEKDAY_INDI
1   6/1/2014    WEEKEND
2   6/2/2014    WEEKDAY
3   6/3/2014    WEEKDAY
4   6/4/2014    WEEKDAY
5   6/5/2014    WEEKDAY
6   6/6/2014    WEEKDAY
7   6/7/2014    WEEKEND
8   6/8/2014    WEEKEND
```

team

```
NAME    DOB          DOB_MONTH    DOJ       UPDATED_DATE
1   Afnand  9/14/2000   September 2/20/2012 6/12/2014
2   Angil   10/9/2000   October  5/5/2014       6/10/2014
3   Asthwini    5/17/2000   May  4/6/2011       6/02/2014
```

Something like the the following SQL should get you started.

```
SELECT t.*, LEAD(tm.BDATE, 5) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY tm.BDATE)
FROM team t
INNER JOIN time_master tm 
   ON tm.BDATE >= t.UPDATED_DATE 
  AND tm.BDATE < t.UPDATED_DATE+10 --10 days to catch long weekends
  AND tm.WEEKDAY_INDI = 'WEEKDAY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in pure sql or pl/sql? Here is pseudo-code for what you could try in pl/sql:

`updated_date DATE;
 FOR i IN 1..5 outerloop
   updated_date := updated_date + 1;
   WHILE updated_date IN holidays.bdate
   innerloop
     updated_date := updated_date + 1;
   END innerloop;
END outerloop;`